# vs code mssql extension - altering a stored procedure

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do i open an existing stored procedure using visual studio code?

I can connect to the database, write queries, but i just do not know how to alter an object that already exists in the database.

I have read the primer that is linked to within the mssql extension documentation but it does not say how to see the code for objects that exist within the database.

Answer (score 7):

While you cannot alter directly you should be able to view the definition and then view the code that way. An easy way to do that is write

```
EXEC SP_Name
```

Then put cursor over and hit F12 which should open the Stored Procedure Definition in a separate window.
This can be done for many SQL objects within vs-code.